# What is wrong with this bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a main folder within which there are a number of folders, each containing a number of text files. I need to run a program on all of these text files. So far I have the following bash script which throws me a syntax error when I try to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in mainfolder/*

for file in ${dir}/*.txt

do

 echo “${file}”
 ./myprogram ${file}

 done

 done
```

The error I get is:

./myscript: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `for'
./myscript: line 5:`for file in ${dir}/*.txt'

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html

Comment: See shellcheck.net

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the first do.

```
#!bin/bash
for dir in mainfolder/*
do
  for file in "${dir}"/*.txt
  do
    echo "${file}"
    ./myprogram "${file}"
  done
done
```

Note the quotes around all variable references. As mentioned in comments, this is an [important measure to take](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667). Also keep in mind that quotes are " ", not “ ”.

Comment: This still uses "pretty" quotes (`”` instead of `"`).

Comment: Oh, and you should quote `${dir}` in the 4th line as well. and `${file}` in the 7th.

Comment: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)